# Parallax effect overlap and Bootstrap wont align div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, parallax

Fairly new to web development. I am attempting to make a responsive website for both mobile and desktop. I'll be honest, its terrible right now. But I'm working on it. I currently have 2 major issues that I've been fighting with for about a full day now. Also Yes I am running django on the backend and vue as a cdn on the front.

1. I have deployed rellax js into the website for a paralax effect however its creating an ugly overlap and I can't seem to get ride of it.
2. Once I deployed rellax js my text that was supposed to be center of the landing page disappeared to the bottom. I would like it centered.
   Could anyone help me with these issues? Also any input as to how to make this mobile friendly would be awesome, I was just going to lock the images at a certain size if the screen was small.

HTML

```
{% include 'core/navbar.html' %} {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}" />
    <link
      
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link
      href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      
    />
    <link
      href="assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css"
      
    />
    <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link
      href="assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link href="assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css"
    />
    <title>Tester Site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="hero" class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <div id="bg">
        <div class="bg">
          <img src="{% static "media/ocean.png" %}" class="bg" alt="" data-rellax-speed="2" data-rellax-percentage="0.5" /> 
          <img src="{% static "media/girl.png" %}" class="girl" data-rellax-speed="7" data-rellax-percentage="0.5" style="top: -195px;  height: 1000px; width: auto;" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="col-sm-2"
        data-aos="zoom-in"
        data-aos-delay="100"
      >
        <h1>
          <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1">e</span>
          <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1">x</span>
          <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1">p</span>
          <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1; padding-right: 8px">l
          </span>
          <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1">o</span>
          <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1">r</span>
          <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1">e</span>
        </h1>
        <h2>
          <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1">C</span>
          <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1">r</span>
          <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1">e</span>
          <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1">a</span>
          <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1">t</span>
          <span
            class="blast"
            aria-hidden="true"
            style="opacity: 1; padding-right: 3px"
            >e</span
          >
          <span
            class="blast"
            aria-hidden="true"
            style="opacity: 1; padding-right: 5px"
            >a</span
          >
          <span
            class="blast"
            aria-hidden="true"
            style="opacity: 1; padding-right: 5px"
          >
            <div id="container">
              <div id="text"></div>
              <div id="cursor"></div>
            </div>
          </span>
        </h2>
        <a href="#about" class="btn-about">About Me</a>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer id="footer" data-rellax-speed="10" data-rellax-percentage="-1.0"></footer>
    


      <section id="about" class="about">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
        <div class="section-title">
          <br>
          <h2>
            <span>A</span>
            <span>b</span>
            <span>o</span>
            <span>u</span>
            <span>t</span>
          </h2>
          <p>Magnam dolores commodi suscipit. Necessitatibus eius consequatur ex aliquid fuga eum quidem. Sit sint consectetur velit. Quisquam quos quisquam cupiditate. Et nemo qui impedit suscipit alias ea. Quia fugiat sit in iste officiis commodi quidem hic quas.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="https://webp.bearsofficialsstore.com/237169917.webp" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8 pt-4 pt-lg-0 content">
            <h3>Illustrator &amp; UI/UX Designer</h3>
            <p class="fst-italic">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
              magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <ul>
                  <li><i class="bi bi-rounded-right"></i> <strong>Birthday:</strong> 1 May 1995</li>
                  <li><i class="bi bi-rounded-right"></i> <strong>Website:</strong> www.example.com</li>
                  <li><i class="bi bi-rounded-right"></i> <strong>Phone:</strong> +123 456 7890</li>
                  <li><i class="bi bi-rounded-right"></i> <strong>City:</strong> City : New York, USA</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <ul>
                  <li><i class="bi bi-rounded-right"></i> <strong>Age:</strong> 30</li>
                  <li><i class="bi bi-rounded-right"></i> <strong>Degree:</strong> Master</li>
                  <li><i class="bi bi-rounded-right"></i> <strong>PhEmailone:</strong> email@example.com</li>
                  <li><i class="bi bi-rounded-right"></i> <strong>Freelance:</strong> Available</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p>
              Officiis eligendi itaque labore et dolorum mollitia officiis optio vero. Quisquam sunt adipisci omnis et ut. Nulla accusantium dolor incidunt officia tempore. Et eius omnis.
              Cupiditate ut dicta maxime officiis quidem quia. Sed et consectetur qui quia repellendus itaque neque. Aliquid amet quidem ut quaerat cupiditate. Ab et eum qui repellendus omnis culpa magni laudantium dolores.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section><!-- End About Section -->
    
    <!-- ======= Skills Section ======= -->
    <section id="skills" class="skills">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2>Skills</h2>
          <p>Magnam dolores commodi suscipit. Necessitatibus eius consequatur ex aliquid fuga eum quidem. Sit sint consectetur velit. Quisquam quos quisquam cupiditate. Et nemo qui impedit suscipit alias ea. Quia fugiat sit in iste officiis commodi quidem hic quas.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row skills-content">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="progress">
              <span class="skill">Video Editing <i class="val">100%</i></span>
              <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="progress">
              <span class="skill">Photoshop <i class="val">90%</i></span>
              <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="progress">
              <span class="skill">Audio Editing <i class="val">75%</i></span>
              <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="progress">
              <span class="skill">Content Creation <i class="val">80%</i></span>
              <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="progress">
              <span class="skill">WordPress/CMS <i class="val">90%</i></span>
              <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section><!-- End Skills Section -->
  </div>
</template>
    <br> 
    <br>  
    <br>  
    <br>  
    <!-- End Hero -->

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/dixonandmoe/rellax@master/rellax.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Center all the things!
      var rellax = new Rellax('.girl', {
        center: false
      });
      var rellax = new Rellax('.bg', {
        center: true
      });
    </script>


    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
    <script>    
    var _CONTENT = [ 
      "Simple Life", 
      "Meaningful life",
      "Positive Life",
      "masterpiece"
    ];

    // Current sentence being processed
    var _PART = 0;

    // Character number of the current sentence being processed 
    var _PART_INDEX = 0;

    // Holds the handle returned from setInterval
    var _INTERVAL_VAL;

    // Element that holds the text
    var _ELEMENT = document.querySelector("#text");

    // Cursor element 
    var _CURSOR = document.querySelector("#cursor");

    // Implements typing effect
    function Type() { 
      // Get substring with 1 characater added
      var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX + 1);
      _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
      _PART_INDEX++;

      // If full sentence has been displayed then start to delete the sentence after some time
      if(text === _CONTENT[_PART]) {
        // Hide the cursor
        _CURSOR.style.display = 'none';

        clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);
        setTimeout(function() {
          _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Delete, 60);
        }, 1000);
      }
    }

    // Implements deleting effect
    function Delete() {
      // Get substring with 1 characater deleted
      var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX - 1);
      _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
      _PART_INDEX--;

      // If sentence has been deleted then start to display the next sentence
      if(text === '') {
        clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);

        // If current sentence was last then display the first one, else move to the next
        if(_PART == (_CONTENT.length - 1))
          _PART = 0;
        else
          _PART++;
        
        _PART_INDEX = 0;

        // Start to display the next sentence after some time
        setTimeout(function() {
          _CURSOR.style.display = 'inline-block';
          _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 120);
        }, 200);
      }
    }
    // Start the typing effect on load
    _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Image 1
[image]

Image 2 after scrolling down

[image]

as you can see the background image that is being scrolled over is popping out on the other side and looks nasty. Any idea how to fix that?

You can also see how the about btn and the txt are all right there at the bottom and not at the top and centered where I am trying to put them.

Any help would be amazing!!